# Reading each Integer from a line from a Text file

Tags: java, text-processing

I am new to Java. How can i read each integer from a line in a text file. I know the reader class has the read and readline functions for it. But in my case i not only want to read the integers in the file but want to know when the line changes. Because the first element of every line denotes an array index and all the corresponding elements are the linked list values attached to that index.

For example, see the 4 line below. In this case i not only want to read each integer but the first integer of every line would be an array index so i will have an a 4 element array with each array element correspoding to a list where A[1]-> 4, A[2]-> 1,3,4 and soo on.

1 4

2 1 3 4

3 2 5

4 2

After retrieving the integers properly i am planning to populate them via

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] aList =  (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[numLines];
```

EDITED : I had been asked in one the comments that what i have thinked soo far and where exctly i am stucken so below is what i am thinking (in terms of original and pseoudo code mixed)..

```
 while (lr.readLine() != null) {

        while ( // loop through each character)
                if ( first charcter)
                    aList[index] = first character;
                else 
                    aList[index]->add(second char.... last char of the line);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far and where you are stucked??

Comment: Hint : Read line and use split function...

Comment: Look to the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  It has handy methods like [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the scanner hint, Andrew Thompson.

This is how i have achieved it

```
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(new File("FileName.txt"));

    ArrayList<Integer>[] aList = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[200];
    String line;
    sc.useDelimiter("\\n");
    int vertex = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        int edge = 0;
        line = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner lineSc = new Scanner(line);
        lineSc.useDelimiter("\\s");
        vertex = lineSc.nextInt() - 1;
        aList[vertex] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int tmp = 0;
        System.out.println(vertex);

        while (lineSc.hasNextInt()) {
            edge = lineSc.nextInt();
            aList[vertex].add(edge);
            System.out.print(aList[vertex].get(tmp) +  "  ");
            ++tmp;
        }
        System.out.println ();
    }
```